# USB DAC not working with Galaxy S9+ on Android 9

Tags: samsung, usb, audio, usb-on-the-go, samsung-galaxy-s-9

I just got a USB DAC/AMP for my S9+ and I can't get any audio to be sent over USB.

Things I've tried:

- Updating from Android 8.0.0 to Android 9
- Confirmed the cable is OTG
- Used Included OTG adaptor with DAC/AMP's included cable
- Confirmed Setup works on friends Galaxy S8

When connecting the DAC/AMP to my S9+ it recognises that the USB device is connected but when I tap to change the USB settings it says that the USB connection is being controlled by the external device but when I tap to switch it to being controlled by the Phone is says "Couldn't Switch" and the DAC/AMP switches off because the connection has been refused.

When connected to my friends S8 it worked straight away no need to change any settings

Comment: [How to enable USB “Audio Source” option on Android 9+?](https://android.stackexchange.com/a/225350/218526)

Answer (score 1):

I found that turning on Hardware Acceleration in Developer Options fixed the issue.