# 2.4 GHz wireless headset connection to Android for calls

Tags: telephony

Got one of these radio wireless 2.4 GHz headphones with a USB dongle (not Bluetooth) - HyperX Cloud Stinger Core Wireless 7.1 PC.

Tried plugging the dongle into my android phone (Galaxy A40, Android 10, 4.4.177-18598463) via an OTG cable and the headphones work with the media output.

But for calls *in Skype and Teams* the sound goes to the phone's speaker.

I guess there might be a standard with these 2.4 GHz wireless headphone dongles because it just works with Android with no additional apps or drivers.

What is the name of the standard?
Is there a way to make calls with an Android with these headphones?

**Edit:** I think the headset gets detected as a USB headset (I checked using the "Device Info HW" app), so the question becomes how do I configure Android to use the USB headset for calls (Skype, Teams).

Comment: Have you seen/tried: [How to enable USB “Audio Source” option on Android 9+?](https://android.stackexchange.com/q/225334/3573)

Comment: @MorrisonChang, thanks, took a look at that, but it doesn't answer my question. It says USB audio source has been deprecated in android 8, so not sure how it's relevant to Android 10. I may need to read up on "USB audio source" to get a better understanding I guess.