# Audio over USB Android

Tags: usb, audio

Hi i have a android phone and want to use the Audio over USB feature  on the phone to connect the audio output to a windows computer
i dont have a usb driver and the windows errors about the driver does anybody know what driver where to get it?

Comment: Please [edit your post](https://android.stackexchange.com/posts/239145/edit) to include the manufacturer/model number/OS version/USB type (micro USB or USB-C) of your android device AND details about your PC (Windows version).

Comment: Related: https://android.stackexchange.com/a/225350/218526

Comment: @MorrisonChang , 
Standaeed Window 10
And a Android phone,
However it  looks like people have abandoned the AOA project , do you have anything that could help.

Comment: @IrfanLatif thanks also