# Why do (certain) peripherals seem to work out of the box for android but need driver installation on desktop?

Tags: usb-peripherals

Recently I was looking for android compatible pen tablets. The ones that have android compatibility works just fine, no driver needed. Only the OTG support (which I assume is for it work as a USB host) and Android 6.0+. While to use any pen tablets, I needed to install drivers on desktop. (though it is mostly automatic).

Why is this the case, even though Android has [no standards](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/63630/why-are-there-not-generic-phone-os-installers?newreg=4d4b971bb29146af89a0e1b29bedfe4d), unlike the PC world?

I know drivers are needed as interface for any kind of hardware-software interaction, but that didn't happen on android in case of pen tablet. Although, not a lot of external hardware was supported on android, anyway, until recently.

(I was not sure where to ask this question as I don't know much about android/drivers/hardware connectivity, and the correct terminologies)

Comment: Drivers on Android/Linux need to run in the Kernel. As the kernel changes frequently most drivers are developed as part of the kernel. Therefore the list of standard drivers already available in Android is usually higher than on Windows.

Comment: Android/Linux kernel does support [USB Device Class Drivers](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/usbcon/supported-usb-classes#usb-device-classes). They are generic drivers supporting many similar devices, not bound to a specific hardware or vendor. An example case is explained [here](https://android.stackexchange.com/a/225350/218526).

Comment: Thanks, both of these comments answer my question